# Substring is getting too less data

Tags: powershell

I want to grab lots of text content from a .sql file between a `--Start` and `--End` comment.

Whatever I do somehow I don`t get the substring method correctly to grab only the text within the --Start and --End comment:

**text.sql**

```
This text I want not
--Start
this text I want here
--End
This text I want not
```

This is what I tried:

```
$insertStartComment = "--Start"
$insertEndComment = "--End"

$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\temp\test.sql")
$insertStartPosition =  $content.IndexOf($insertStartComment) + $insertStartComment.Length

$insertEndPosition =    $content.IndexOf($insertEndComment)
$content1 = $content.Substring($insertStartPosition, $content1.Length - $insertEndPosition)
$content = $content1.Substring(0,$content1.Length - $insertEndPosition)
```

It would be nice if someone could help me out find my error :-)

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is it is getting too less text and I do not understand why.

Comment: It would be nice if you'd edit the post and add the actual results too. When I ran the sample, there was an error about substring index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an attempt to use uninitialized variable in the code:

```
$content1 = $content.Substring($insertStartPosition, $content1.Length - $insertEndPosition)
```

The variable `$content1` isn't initialized yet, thus the substring call goes haywire. When you run the code again, the variable is set - and results are even more weird.

Use Powershell's `Set-StrictMode` to enable warnings about uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the substring approach you are looking for, but I figured that I would toss out a RegEx solution. This will find the text between the --Start and --End on a text file. In this case, I am grouping the matched text with a named capture called LineYouWant and display the matches that it finds. This also works if you have multiple instances of --Start--End blocks in a single file.

```
$Text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("C:\users\proxb\desktop\SQL.txt")
[regex]::Matches($Text,'.*--Start\s+(?<LineYouWant>.*)\s+--End.*') | ForEach {
    $_.Groups['LineYouWant'].Value
}
```